# boost::io_service run() never returns sometimes

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I have the following code to read data from a RS232 port. For some (from beginning) runs, `io.run()` returns immediately and `m_handler()` is called which is expected. but sometimes (a fresh run from beginning), `io.run()` goes into a inside forever loop(stacked inside forever) even for the first time called inside the while loop. And this happens randomly. What's is/are the potential problem(s) at here?

```
#define BUF_SIZE    512
char data[BUF_SIZE];

void my_handler(const boost::system::error_code& err, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
printf("%d\n", bytes_transferred);
if (!err){
   process_data();
}
}


void test_serial_port( int argc, char* argv[]  )
{
// hard coded parameters
const char *PORT = "COM1";
serial_port_base::baud_rate BAUD(9600);
serial_port_base::character_size CSIZE( 8 );
serial_port_base::flow_control FLOW( serial_port_base::flow_control::software );
serial_port_base::parity PARITY( serial_port_base::parity::none );
serial_port_base::stop_bits STOP( serial_port_base::stop_bits::one );

io_service io;
serial_port port( io, PORT );


// go through and set all the options as we need them
// all of them are listed, but the default values work for most cases
port.set_option( BAUD );
port.set_option( CSIZE );
port.set_option( FLOW );
port.set_option( PARITY );
port.set_option( STOP );

while( !kbhit() )
{
    io.reset();

    port.async_read_some( 
        boost::asio::buffer(data, BUF_SIZE), 
        boost::bind(&my_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred )
        );

    io.run();

    Sleep(300);
}
}
```

Comment: it's not clear why you're using `async_read_some()` in this context instead of `read_some()`?

Comment: I'm not sure what a stacked inside forever loop is, but the described behavior of blocking would result if no data is being received on the serial port.  Consider using breakout equipment or virtualization with terminal apps to verify data throughput.

Comment: This is a good point. i will try to use hyperterminal to debug this issue.